# Не работает location редирект в success функции AJAX

Tags: ajax, laravel, redirect

столкнулся со следующей проблемой, есть код:

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/cabinet";
        },
        error: function(data){
            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            //console.log(errors['errors']);
            $.each(errors['errors'], function( key, value ) {
                //console.log(key+' : '+value);
                $('.login_'+key+'_error').children().text(value);
                $('.login_'+key+'_error').css('display', 'block');
            });
        }
    });
```

При успешном callback'e не происходит редирект, в чем проблема ?
Пробовал самыми разными способами, и relative ссылки, и абсолютные, и метод assign(), вообще ни в какую. Ни один ответ тут не помог решить проблему.
Заранее спасибо!

Comment: проверил, нету входа в функцию success, однако и эту проблему, найденные решения не смогли убрать

Comment: в консоли также есть ошибка, что массив ошибок с response пуст, но исходя из этого есть догадка что мы все равно попадаем в error. Использовал дефолтную систему авторизации laravel, может что то нужно изменить в контроллерах ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: $(this).attr('action'),
        data: $(this).serializeArray(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) {
            alert(1);
        },
        error: function(data){
            if (data.responseJSON == undefined) {
                alert(1);
                window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/cabinet";
            }

            var errors = data.responseJSON;
            //console.log(errors['errors']);
            $.each(errors['errors'], function( key, value ) {
                //console.log(key+' : '+value);
                $('.login_'+key+'_error').children().text(value);
                $('.login_'+key+'_error').css('display', 'block');
            });
        }
    });
```

Вопрос решил следующим образом, а именно проверкой на ошибки непосредственно в поле errors, раз оно вызывается. Полагаю что решение костыльное, но по крайней мере работает как надо. Если кто-то знает как решить проблему правильно, буду рад услышать такое решение.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте так:

```
success: window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/cabinet";
```